# Pass **kwargs if not none

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to pass `**kwargs` to another function but only if it is not null. Right now I have this `if else` and I am wondering if there is a more efficient more pythonic way?

```
 if other:
     html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected, **other))
 else:
     html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected))
```

If other is `NoneType` then I get the error:

```
...argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

Comment: Why are you worried about it?  Just pass them; you don't get an error if there are none, do you?

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be shorter, cleaner, or more Pythonic. I would probably test explicitly (`if other is not None` rather than `if other`) but that's really only for syntactic flair, certainly would never effect execution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do get an error if other is none `argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use either

```
html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected, **(other or {})))
```

or

```
html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected, **(other if other is not None else {})))
```

or the more explicit

```
if other is None:
    other = {}
html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected, **other))
```

Passing an empty dict as kwargs should be the same as not specifying kwargs.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment, but it requires formatting and is too big to fit in a comment.

I suggested:

> Why are you worried about it? Just pass them; you don't get an error if there are none, do you?

The response was:

> I do get an error if `other` is none: `argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`

#### Counter-example

```
def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
  for k in kwargs:
    print k, " => ", kwargs[k]

def kwargs_demo(a, **kwargs):
  print a
  print_kwargs(**kwargs)

kwargs_demo(1)
kwargs_demo(99, **{'cat':'dog', 'ice':'cream'})
```

#### Output

```
1
99
ice  =>  cream
cat  =>  dog
```

#### Reconnecting the disconnect?

There must be a disconnect between what you're doing and what I think you're doing (and what it appears your question title is asking about).  I can generate the error you see with the call to `kwargs_mark2()` in the code below:

```
def kwargs_mark2(a):
  print a
  other = None
  print_kwargs(**other)  # Fails with 'must be a mapping, not NoneType'

kwargs_mark2(24)
```

The fix is fairly straight-forward (and illustrated in `kwargs_mark3()`): don't create a `None` object when a mapping is required — create an empty mapping.

```
def kwargs_mark3(a):
  print a
  other = {}
  print_kwargs(**other)

kwargs_mark3(37)
```

Comment: it wasn't meant to be a riposte. It was meant to be a standard reply.  I apologize. I love the idea of not creating a `None` in the first place. That is much smarter. I'll try and figure out how I got that error. I am using Flask with Python 2.7, but that should not matter.

Comment: I'll downgrade 'riposte' to 'response'. I wasn't taking offense, or dreadfully upset (heck; it forced me to go and improve my flaky Python).